# How should I use Favorite Tags to help Stack Overflow decide which questions are most interesting?

Tags: support, tag-watching

I would like to be able to specify (or even better, have Stack Overflow figure it out for me) that some of my favorite tags are more important than others, and make a question 'more interesting' on the Stack Overflow home page.

For example, my favorite tags include "c#" and "javascript". I have more experience with C# than JavaScript, so I am more likely to consider a C# question interesting. It would be nice to have the most interesting questions be more prominent on the home page. Maybe it would be better to have a separate page with questions sorted by 'interestingness'. As it is, the questions that interest me are being crowded out by the ones that have one of my favorite tags, but are not actually interesting to me.

Part of the problem may be that I have too many favorite tags, but if I remove some, then there will be less interesting questions that I see.

I want to call this a feature request, but I'm sure there is a better existing way to get the most relevant questions in front of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just click on the `c#` tag to the right and it will only display questions to you that are tagged with `c#`. Then you can sort them by one of the options available and be on your merry way, it's a whole stack of questions specific to that!

You can also try out the [advanced search features](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=) to exclude questions tagged with something else, and maybe if you find a certain search that you really like, bookmark it in your browser.

This query will show all questions tagged with `c#` that have no answers yet and are not closed, sorted by newest questions:

[`/search?tab=newest&q=%5bc%23%5d%20answers%3a0%20closed%3a0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bc%23%5d%20answers%3a0%20closed%3a0)

Play around with additional tag inclusions or exclusions and find lists that interest you. All the tools are there already.

Comment: Thanks. That still doesn't explain how to include other tags but at less prominence.

Comment: You can't. But you can view the C# questions first, since you find them more interesting, then view the JavaScript questions. What you're talking about is not possible. The unicorns are not powerful enough to magically sort questions based on how interesting they *might* be to you. You complains about the questions you'd find interesting being crowded out, and this is an excellent way to get *only* questions you'd potentially find interesting on the page. You can even modify that list to include only questions tagged with `c#` *or* `javascript`.